# How can I add support for ES6 symbol view for atom editor?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, atom-editor

I research and try many packages and none can recognize javascript ES6 keyword like `class`, `=>` or even function nor method declared in the class.

FYI: https://github.com/atom/symbols-view help display a list of functions and allow jump to declaration immediately.

Comment: I Know notepad ++ does  this

Comment: Did you disable the default javascript language pack? It works for me with ES6

Comment: works for me, using seti syntax theme

Comment: i don't see ES6 class symbols in the CMD+R list either.. my `language-javascript` package is not disabled..